# How can add JSON array into Google App datastore

Tags: java, json, google-app-engine

I need solution to add a JSON array to store into google app datastore, I think it would possible in Python, but I am not familiar with this, I need only simple implementation in Java code and JSON layout to store received data from and Android accelemeter into datastore. It will be nice if anyone can help me.

Answer (score 4):

If you don't need to index the data, simply store the JSON data as a text string in the datastore, marked as not indexed. If you do need it indexed, you will need to construct a model that contains the important properties of the JSON data, and copy values over yourself.

Comment: RESTeasy has been nice for mapping JSON to Java classes.  Objectify has been nice for mapping Java classes to the datastore.

Comment: Datastore StringProperty has a limitation of 500 characters. TextProperty is up to 1 MB for bigger files you will need a blob.

Answer (score 1):

See [here](https://code.google.com/p/latke/source/browse/trunk/latke-gae/src/main/java/org/b3log/latke/repository/gae/GAERepository.java) for a implementation of JSON <-> Entity mapping.

```
 /**
 * Sets the properties of the specified entity by the specified json object.
 *
 * @param entity the specified entity
 * @param jsonObject the specified json object
 * @throws JSONException json exception
 */
public static void setProperties(final Entity entity,
                                 final JSONObject jsonObject)
        throws JSONException {
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    final Iterator<String> keys = jsonObject.keys();
    while (keys.hasNext()) {
        final String key = keys.next();
        final Object value = jsonObject.get(key);

        if (!GAE_SUPPORTED_TYPES.contains(value.getClass())
            && !(value instanceof Blob)) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Unsupported type[class=" + value.
                    getClass().getName() + "] in Latke GAE repository");
        }

        if (value instanceof String) {
            final String valueString = (String) value;
            if (valueString.length()
                > DataTypeUtils.MAX_STRING_PROPERTY_LENGTH) {
                final Text text = new Text(valueString);

                entity.setProperty(key, text);
            } else {
                entity.setProperty(key, value);
            }
        } else if (value instanceof Number
                   || value instanceof Date
                   || value instanceof Boolean
                   || GAE_SUPPORTED_TYPES.contains(value.getClass())) {
            entity.setProperty(key, value);
        } else if (value instanceof Blob) {
            final Blob blob = (Blob) value;
            entity.setProperty(key,
                               new com.google.appengine.api.datastore.Blob(
                    blob.getBytes()));
        }
    }
}
```